# Hibernate is getting wrong ID values when using UUID as primary key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "eh_portal")
public class PortalEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "CHAR(36)")
    private UUID id; //java.util.UUID;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "url")
    private String url;

    // -- Constructor for Hibernate --
    protected PortalEntity() {
    }

    // -- Constructor for new entity in service code --
    public PortalEntity(final UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    .... getters and setters ommited
}
```

Respository is Spring DATA JPA:

```
public interface PortalRepository extends CrudRepository<PortalEntity, UUID> {

}
```

MYSQL 5 Database table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `eh_portal` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL COMMENT 'UUID',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `url_UNIQUE` (`url`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The problem is, Hibernate is returning obviously wrong data - see screenshots below
Mysql workbench:

[image]

Actual web page where I get entities thru Spring Data JPA:
[image]

You can see that UUIDs are obviously differrent, while other columns are correct. 
What is wrong here? (Spring 4, Hibernate 4, Spring DATA JPA, Mysql 5)

Comment: Is it really wrong or just the output on your screen. Could be a simple rendering/conversion issue.. Also what are you printing, the ID directly or using a converter, I'm also wondering if hibernate natively supports UUID to String and back conversion or if you need a converter.

Comment: I have debugged the returned entites. It is wrong at entites level.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using `@Type(type="uuid-char")`.

Comment: This solved my problem when my entity is unable to load its children entities.

Comment: Could you please explain why this works and/or is necessary? Thanks